# error in playing a video of 720*480 resolution in android application from sd card

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to play a video stored in sd card.When i run the code its showing error sry video cannot be played.Dont know what the error actually is ..I have done a lot of r and d.But cant find the exact solution.I have tried with different formats.But not working,.My java class code is http://pastebin.com/KXSGu4Ux.I will be really thankful to you

Can anyone help me this regard

Thanks in advance
Tushar